# Datanucleus JDO - what jars do I need?

Tags: java, installation, jdo

**Context:**

I am learning Java, and am building a web application as a study(learn by doing). I've decided to use JDO(datanucleus) and H2 for persistence. I am a novice with the Java language, so feel free to consider me pathetically ignorant =)

**Question:**

Which of the included Jars are required in my classpath? I currently have:

- api-jdo-3.0.0
- core-3.0.0
- rdbms-3.0.0
- jdo-api-3.1 (javax.jdo package)
- log4j-1.2.14

I have read through the documentation at [Datanucleus.org](http://www.datanucleus.org) and I have downloaded the "accessplatform-rdbms-3.0.0-release" from sourceforge. I have also installed the datanucleus plugin for Eclipse(indigo).

To select the ones I have above: I opened up the jars and hunted down the classes referenced in the documentation, and I also found the site [MavenHub](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.0.0-release) (I'm not using maven btw) and it looks like there is a dependency listing there. However the access platform contains its own "api-jdo-3.0.0" jar (in addition to the Apache one in the deps\ folder) and a "rdbms-3.0.0" jar. Neither of these are mentioned in the MavenHub dependency list.

I understand that some of the jars provide additional features that I wont need, but I cant seem to find a "basic" implementation list.  There are 14 jars in the lib/ folder ("jdo-query-3.0.0" looks pretty important for example). Can anyone advise me on this, or better yet, enlighten me (link a hand holding tutorial or a resource like MavenHub i can use)?

(I was kinda dubious about the MavenHub list because it seemed overly brief.)

Thanks for helping me out

***EDIT:***

Moved Answer so question appears as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, both on the website and in the tutorial downloads.

For any others:

As DataNucleus pointed out; on the [website](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/guides/jdo/tutorial.html) it is under the "enhance your classes" section of the guide.

```
src/java/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/tutorial/Book.java
src/java/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/tutorial/Inventory.java
src/java/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/tutorial/Product.java

target/classes/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/tutorial/Book.class
target/classes/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/tutorial/Inventory.class
target/classes/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/tutorial/Product.class

lib/jdo-api.jar
lib/datanucleus-core.jar
lib/datanucleus-api-jdo.jar
lib/datanucleus-enhancer.jar
lib/asm.jar
```

The other location is on the [Datanucleus Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/), there are samples:

"datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial-3.0-src.zip" has several Readme files in it and in those files, it lists the necessary files:

```
DataNucleus Tutorial for JDO at the CommandLine
===============================================
Download the necessary jars and put them into the lib/ directory
You will need :-
datanucleus-core.jar
datanucleus-enhancer.jar
datanucleus-api-jdo.jar
datanucleus-rdbms.jar
asm.jar (3.0)
log4j.jar (1.2.*)
jdo-api.jar (3.0)
(your-jdbc-driver.jar)
```

The listing on the site is easy to miss, (I did despite looking several times).  Additonally, you have to import (either-or):

```
javax.jdo.annotations.[classes];
javax.jdo.[classes];
```

from the Apache jdo-api.jar to use annotations in your classes, and to reference the Persistence Managers depending on what your doing in the class.

Comment: The tutorial actually states the jars needed for the various steps, on http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/guides/jdo/tutorial.html

Comment: @DataNucleus It's sometimes unclear from tutorials, especially if you're trying to adapt from “just download this ZIP with everything in” to “list of relevant Maven artifacts”. Not that this is a problem specific to DataNucleus; I've had to put up with it in many projects where the tutorial creator has tried to avoid talking about the integration question.

Comment: @Donal Understood, but as with all of our docs, they are in SVN available for patches and contributions.

Comment: @Datanucleus  -- You 100% right, I must have looked at that page a dozen times and still never recognized it!  I have updated the answer to reflect it. Thanks.